# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined "jquery-ui.js:338"

Tags: jquery

My jquery script reference are :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m
 - And I'm getting an error on line 338

```
})( jQuery );  //--> line 338 is highlighted
```

This is a 1st for me and looking for answers.

I'm in the process of learning how to use the API and have a simple webpage

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#edit-user" )
                .button()
                .click(function() {
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                });         
     });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="edit-user">Edit User</button>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Radio Dialog">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <input type='radio' value='A' name='myRadio'>A
                <input type='radio' value='B' name='myRadio'>B
                <input type='radio' value='C' name='myRadio'>C
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any code for how you are using jquery?

Comment: Have you got any other script on your page ?

Comment: @Chad Sellers Yeah, we're gonna need more code info than that...

Comment: If I create a blank HTML page that only has those two scripts (in the order posted) included in it, then there is no error. A link would be fantastic, but, for now, what other scripts are you including on that page (before the ones you posted)?

Comment: @Chad Sellers Yeah your links to jQuery are right, so it must be something in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information you provided I assume that you expect som kind of dialog to open, right?

Your dialog is actually already present anyway but, for the sake of seeing that something is happening, start with hiding it (but do this using .css instead when you implement it for real later on):

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Radio Dialog" style='display:none;'>
```

Then it seems like you need to create the dialog before you open it. This is most likely what stopped you from moving ahead:

```
$(function() {

        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false      
        });      

        $( "#edit-user" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
         });         
     });
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NjpBU/)

Hope this helps you solve whatever problem you had!

Comment: Glad it worked. One more thing, the .button() you chained, not sure about your intention, but this code needs to be run after the button has been loaded. And I think you need to include the theme-css files as well for it to work... correct me if I'm wrong anyone.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include jquery first

Comment: The example shows that they are including jQuery first.